# Intellij not resolving python libs in external (to project dirs) file

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I did a file|add for a python script that is not under project root. IJ knows it is python but for some reason does not use the python facet (python 2.7.3) and module already defined for this project.

[image: Unresolved standard imports and functions]

Do i have to copy the file to my project dirs? that defeats purpose of opening a file manually..

Comment: I'm also having this issue, did you find an answer for this?